# How can I create multiple hashes of a file using only one pass?

Tags: python, hash

How can I get a MD5, SHA and other hashes from a file but only doing one pass? I have 100mb files, so I'd hate to process those 100MB files multiple times.

Comment: see also [Simultaneously calculate multiple digests (md5, sha256)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163747/simultaneously-calculate-multiple-digests-md5-sha256)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a modified [`@ʞɔıu`'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537542/how-can-i-create-multiple-hashes-of-a-file-using-only-one-pass/537585#537585) using [`@Jason S`' suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537542/how-can-i-create-multiple-hashes-of-a-file-using-only-one-pass/537597#537597).

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from hashlib import md5, sha1

filename = 'hash_one-pass.py'

hashes = md5(), sha1()
chunksize = max(4096, max(h.block_size for h in hashes))
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    while True:
        chunk = f.read(chunksize)
        if not chunk:
            break
        for h in hashes:
            h.update(chunk)

for h in hashes:
    print h.name, h.hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 15):

Something like this perhaps?

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashes = (hashlib.md5(), hashlib.sha1())
>>> f = open('some_file', 'r')
>>> for line in f:
...     for hash in hashes:
...         hash.update(line)
... 
>>> for hash in hashes:
...     print hash.name, hash.hexdigest()
```

or loop over f.read(1024) or something like that to get fixed-length blocks

Comment: That looks like it would work but I would read bytes using a fixed block size rather than a per-line basis (some binary files may not contain line breaks)

Comment: f.readlines() requires ~100MB, but a mere `f` works (a file object is an iterator over lines in Python)

Comment: `for line in f` iterates over *lines* in the file. if line size is 1MB then it doesn't matter what buffer size do you use; len(line) will be 2**20. Therefore the 3rd parameter for the `open()` is not useful in this case.

Comment: you may be right, maybe I don't understand the meaning of that parameter correctly

Answer (score 3):

I don't know Python but I am familiar w/ hash calculations.

If you handle the reading of files manually, just read in one block (of 256 bytes or 4096 bytes or whatever) at a time, and pass each block of data to update the hash of each algorithm. (you'll have to initialize state at the beginning and finalize the state at the end.)